Delete User (Token)
I have been blocked for a while to delete a user from my dashboard. Here, we want only the user can delete his own account, OR if I have the role of admin, I must be able to do so as well.
Auth.js :
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import {env} from "../config/index.js"
import { newError } from "./error.js"

// Vérification du Token
export const Token = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.access_token;

    if (!token) return next(newError(401, "Accès refusé."))

    jwt.verify(token, env.TOKEN, (err, user) => {
        if(err) {
            return next(newError(403, "Token non valide."))
        }
    req.user = user;
    next();

})}

**This is the controller concerning **:
// DELETE USER
export const deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
    try { // On vérifie si l'utilisateur existe :
        const response = await userModel.findById(req.params.id);

        if(!response) return res.status(404).json({message: "Utilisateur non trouvé."});

        if(req.user.id !== response._id.toString() && req.user.role !== 'admin'){
            return res.status(403).json({message: "Accès refusé : vous n'êtes pas l'utilisateur concerné."})
        }

        // Suppression de l'utilisateur
        await userModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json({message: "Utilisateur supprimé avec succès."});

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Erreur lors de la tentative de suppression : ", error);
    }
};

This is the request I send from react:
 const deleteUser = async (id) => {
    const userAuth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
    const auth = userAuth && JSON.parse(userAuth);

    if(auth.role === "admin") {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/delete/${id}`)
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response)
        alert("Utilisateur supprimé avec succès");
        setUsers((prevUsers) => prevUsers.filter((user) => user._id !== id));} // On met à jour le state local en retirant de la liste l'item supprimé.
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Erreur lors de la suppression de l'utilisateur", error)
    }
  }}

And here is the error code in the terminal:
Error: Accès refusé.
    at newError (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PureKrea/back/middlewares/error.js:2:19)
    at Token (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PureKrea/back/middlewares/auth.js:9:29)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\PureKrea\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\PureKrea\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\PureKrea\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\Puad.

Can you help me? I really don’t know where it bothers. I think the problem comes from my controller but without knowing more.
I want to be able to delete any user if I have the status "admin". Users can delete their own account normally.
